# Spree internalization default_locale stays :en

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

[Spree I18n](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/i18n.html#the-default-locale)

> 2.3 Setting the Default Locale
>
> The default locale for Spree is en. This can be changed by editing the :default_locale setting in the AppConfiguration model. This setting is ignored unless the relevant translation file are within #{Rails.root}/config/locales or the spree_i18n gem. In the future we hope to add a localization settings page that will allow you to set the default locale from the admin screen.

I made a new app, followed spree installation, added gem 'spree_i18n' to Gemfile.
Added the hu-Hu.yml file to config/locales, but can't get the hugnarian translation to be default.

I even tried to do:

```
 rails c
 irb(main):001:0> I18n.default_locale = :hu
 => :hu
```

There is no app_configuration.rb in my model directory.

Q: Where should i set the default_locale?

Edit:
If i set in application.rb

```
    config.i18n.default_locale = :hu
```

i get errors like:

[image]

Comment: Do you have translations in your file `config/locales/hu.yml`?

Comment: i have them in config/locales /hu-Hu.yml
edit: renamed it to hu.yml , but still the same problem like on the printscreen

Comment: Then try to rename it according to the name of the locale , in your case: `hu.yml`.

Comment: Just did it, but got the same error, like on printscreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure correct locale name is assigned to `config.i18n.default_locale` in `config/application.rb` like:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :hu
```

and the translation file in config/locales like

```
config/locales/spree_i18n.hu.yml
```

and if the contents of this file looks correct - at the top the translation tree should start with `hu:`

All above paths are relative to the root of project's tree, of course.

**Update:**
It looks like the translation file for Hungarian(?) is missing in official spree_i18n sources. I just found one at [https://github.com/minktom/spree_i18n](https://github.com/minktom/spree_i18n/blob/master/config/locales/hu.yml) Save it as described above and hope you are set.

Comment: Done this, now tried with spree_i18n.hu.yml filename, i got the yml from github original spree i18n, 
gem 'spree_i18n', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git'
i got the newest spree_i18n , still the same problem like on sreenshot

Comment: @RailsBeginner Check the contents of spree_i18n.hu.yml for `my_account` key. If missing, it means the translation file is incomplete and you either have to get some more complete version from other place or fill the missing pairs by yourself.